# how to create Multilevel dropdown using asp tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown in ASP.net webforms, I want to create a another dropdown based on first level selection.

> Say, 1.Furniture 
>           2.Electronics -> i.TV
>                         ii.Mobile

Is it possible to do like above only by using asp tag or adding second level like TV and Mobile in C# code.

```
`<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" Width="200px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Category" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Furniture" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Electronics" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>`
```

Note: I don't want to display it dynamically even though it is preferable.
Please help me in this problem

Comment: You're using this thing for Menu navigation or for some other features of your application?

Comment: It's just an existing dropdown in my application and i want to modify it to multilevel

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap 3.0.0 dropdown menu

Visit this link

[Click Here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Comment: I think OP don't want to use this thing for menu's. And another thing is he just want to use plain `asp` tags.